# Authlib for Flask App getting param_error

Tags: flask, authlib, untappd

I'm using the Authlib module to test OAuth2 integration. I made a simple Flask app and am trying to Authorize with the Untappd API (https://untappd.com/api/docs#authentication).

Following the guidelines of the Authlib Flask module (https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/flask.html), I get as far as successfully being redirected and getting an authorization code.

After `authorize_redirect()` redirects me to authorize my app at Untappd, I approve, sending me to my callback url with the auth code in the url.

```
http://localhost:3000/callback?code=1B6D5B8154EC6627748001F&state=GwqinEMqcRDSjfKmNHh
```

I should be able to next call `authorize_access_token()` to get a token, but this is what I get:

```
{'meta': {'http_code': 500, 'error_type': 'param_error', 'error_detail': 'Missing either the client_id, redirect_url, client_secret or code parameter. Please check your request a try again.'}, 'response': []}
```

I've registered client_id, redirect_url, client_secret in authlib's config so I don't know what is missing. Using an authorization code **I tested in Postman and successfully received a token**

```
  GET  https://untappd.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET&response_type=code&redirect_url=REDIRECT_URL&code=CODE

{"meta":{"http_code":200},"access_token":"k43l4j3lj43lj43","response":{"access_token":"k43l4j3lj43lj43"}}
```

**So what's wrong with my code?:**

```
auth0 = oauth.register(
    'auth0',
    client_id=AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    api_base_url=AUTH0_BASE_URL,
    access_token_url=AUTH0_BASE_URL + '/oauth/authorize',
    authorize_url=AUTH0_BASE_URL + '/oauth/authenticate',
)


@auth_blueprint.route('/login')
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for('.callback', _external=True)
    return auth0.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)


@auth_blueprint.route('/callback')
def callback():
    token = auth0.authorize_access_token()
    print(token)
    return redirect('/loggedin')
```

The only thing I can think of is that the authorization code is not passed in the redirect, but am not able to debug it. What's happening behind the scenes in Authlib is not well documented in my opinion.

**Update**
I had an idea to run `print(auth0.__dict__)` to see if I can see what param are missing.

```
{'name': 'auth0', 'client_id': '2226808DCDAF2FA5FFE145A', 'client_secret': '9494F1877AB0D01D9DE6AAF4', 'request_token_url': None, 'request_token_params': None, 'access_token_url': 'https://untappd.com/oauth/authorize', 'access_token_params': None, 'authorize_url': 'https://untappd.com/oauth/authenticate', 'authorize_params': None, 'api_base_url': 'https://untappd.com', 'client_kwargs': {}, 'oauth1_client_cls': None, 'oauth2_client_cls': <class 'authlib.integrations.requests_client.oauth2_session.OAuth2Session'>, 'compliance_fix': None, 'client_auth_methods': None, '_fetch_token': None, '_update_token': None, '_server_metadata_url': None, 'server_metadata': {'refresh_token_url': None, 'refresh_token_params': None}, '_fetch_request_token': None, '_save_request_token': None}
```

(id and secret not real)
I don't see anything that is not there that should be.

Comment: It seems like auth0 object is missing parameter when calling from callback route. can you follow this code: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-python-web-app/blob/master/01-Login/server.py

Comment: That is the mystery. That example is basically identical to what I've done. Just had an idea to `print(auth0.__dict__)` to see what values there are. will update with that info.

Comment: I have a very similar issue, but I am able to see what's happening on the KeyCloak side.  The Authlib for Flask isn't passing the required `redirect_uri` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting down this road too, so I don't have much to offer.

But one thing I know is that Untappd are fussy about generic User-Agent strings. Try over-riding that. Perhaps Postman did the same thing..?..

In my code, I added this and all worked well
`oauth.headers["User-Agent"] = "GiveMeBeer"`